# Log out of Documentum Server

Tags: c#, documentum, dfc, documentum-dfs

I have an Windows application that uses Documentum APIs to checkin/checkout documents into Documentum Content Server 6.5.1.

I use DFS 6.5.1 to interact with the server.

Now I need to logout of the session. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your question, what do you mean by log out of the session.

You don't log out sessions, you release them to a session manager (if you are using one) or disconnect them directly.

Comment: and finally that is what I did..Thanks